# Validating an emoji sequence with ICU4C

Tags: emoji, icu, icu4c

Is there any way I can use ICU4C to check if a string is *definitely* an emoji? Specifically according to these specifications:

http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-15.html

I can use the regexes or ebnf patterns mentioned there to scan for possible emojis, but validating them according to the rules remains a problem.

*From these EBNF rules a regex can be generated, as below. While this regex may seem complex, it is far simpler than what would result from the definitions. Direct use of the definitions would result in regex expressions which are many times more complicated, and yet **still require verification with validity tests**.*

```
  \p{RI} \p{RI}
| \p{Emoji} 
  ( \p{EMod} 
    | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? 
    | [\x{E0020}-\x{E007E}]+ \x{E007F} )?
  (\x{200D} \p{Emoji} 
    ( \p{EMod}
      | \x{FE0F} \x{20E3}? )?)+
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: @DS. It's 4 years ago, but I don't think I ever found and answer to the question. However, I just pasted this into GPT, and it claimed ICU4C provides custom regex functionality that could be used.

Comment: The best answer I found is here: https://github.com/gristlabs/grist-core/blob/9d10ac829277ce31b318ce4d1e63dc06d1c90386/app/client/ui2018/pages.ts#L135 (see comments for the source references). It's still not perfect, but "official" and I think the best you can get without including detailed tables.